# BroadcastReceiver android repeating message issue

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I use notificationlistener to obtain messages to show in a lockscreen application I work on. I researched but could not find a solution for an issue.

For example i send test message hi, how are you, how is weather:
reciever shows in lock screen:

joseph: hi
joseph: 1 new messages
joseph: how are you
joseph: 2 new messages

Normal case, lock screens, i see they are grouped and says at bottom once only.

Hi
How are you
2 new messages

I tried to create Intent for each sender app (I could not find how to obtain appname from intent object too). If i manually check string with "contains new message" to not show, since not just SMS but all messages without app distintiction, i could not understand how to identify which message is from which app.

My broadcast listener code as follows:

```
private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");


 try {
//                remotePackageContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pack, 0);
//                Drawable icon = remotePackageContext.getResources().getDrawable(id);
//                if(icon !=null) {
//                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setBackground(icon);
//                }
                byte[] byteArray =intent.getByteArrayExtra("icon");
                Bitmap bmp = null;

                if(byteArray !=null)
                {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                }
                CL_mesaj m1 = new CL_mesaj();
                m1.name      = title +": " + text;
                m1.imaBitmap = bmp;

                if(arrl_mesajlar ==null)
                {
                    arrl_mesajlar = new ArrayList<CL_mesaj>();
                    arrl_mesajlar.add(m1);
                    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrl_mesajlar);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else
                {
                    arrl_mesajlar.add(m1);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```